# jquery selectors

Tags: jquery

I would like to select the p elements inside a particular div, #homepage. I know how to select all the #homepage, or all of the li's on the page, but how do I selected a nested group of li's?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is:

```
$('#homepage p')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#homepage p"); // All the `p` tags inside `div#homepage`
```

You need to look at the [jQuery Documentation for Selectors](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors) and specifically the section titled Hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

You can nest selectors by separating them with a space.

In your case, `$('#homepage p')` matches all `p` elements that are inside (directly or nested) a `#homepage` element.

If you only want `p`s that are *directly* inside `#homepage`, use a child selector, like this:  `$('#homepage > p')`.

For more information, read the [documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors).

Answer (score 0):

`$("div#homepage p")` or `$("div#homepage>p")` if you need "direct" children of `#homepage`.

Answer (score 0):

For a nested group of li's

```
$("#homepage li li");
```